# Send multiple data with the same name

Tags: php, post, input, foreach

I have multiple input fields with the same name. How do I print these fields with foreach?

```
 <!-- One Child -->
 <input type="text" name="child_name[]">
 <input type="text" name="child_date[1]">
 <input type="text" name="child_date[1]">
 <input type="text" name="child_date[1]">

 <!-- Two Child -->
 <input type="text" name="child_name[]">
 <input type="text" name="child_date[2]">
 <input type="text" name="child_date[2]">
 <input type="text" name="child_date[2]">
```

Comment: Will you be getting these inputs from a post?

Comment: these are the fields to be filled in by users

Comment: So the users will fill out the inputs, they will be sent to your server with POST, and in PHP you want to print?

Comment: I want to do exactly as you say.

Comment: Are you asking for advice on how to do this? Or is there a specific problem on you have?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you give an example of php code on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

if you used an input array on the form, instead of manually populating the input names with a number concatenated. Example:-

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname[]" />
<input type="text" name="fieldname[]" />
<input type="text" name="fieldname[]" />
```

On the PHP side, simply loop over them:-

```
$fieldname = $_POST['fieldname'];

foreach($fieldname as $index => $a_name){
    $output.= $index . ': '.$a_name . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I know this method. there is more input. For example;
Room  1 -> Child Total -> Child Birthday 1 and Child Birthday 2 and Child Birthday 3
Room  2 -> Child Total -> Child Birthday 1 and Child Birthday 2 and Child Birthday 3
I can't do it like in the example with the method you say

Comment: @Tamer please explain it by diagram.

Comment: Adults -> 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 (select menu)
Child -> 1 - 2 - 3 (select menu)
1 Child Date (input text)
2 Child Date (input text)
3 Child Date (input text)
Baby -> 1 - 2 - 3 (select menu)
(multiple same name forms)

I can get data except dates. Dates do not come by field.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual form?  Or put the code for the form in the question?